# How to access subdiretory as subdomain?

Tags: php, server, dns, subdomain, cpanel

On my website, whenever a user registers, a directory is created by its username. For example :-www.subkuchh.com/user1. In every such directory, an index.php page is created dynamically. I want visitors to access

www.subkuchh.com/user1

www.subkuchh.com/user2

www.subkuchh.com/user3

....

www.subkuchh.com/usern

as

user1.subkuchh.com

user2.subkuchh.com

...

usern.subkuchh.com

To accomplish this I have added A name record as *.subkuchh.com and pointed it to my server ip but I am stuck at .htaccess part. I have tried many codes and methods available on internet to get this done but haven't succeeded. Please help me.

Comment: what .htaccess have you tried so far?

Comment: Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([aA-zZ])$  index.php?username=$1

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(^.*)\.subkuchh.com
RewriteRule (.*)  index.php?username=%1